# presentViewController is crash in iOS8

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, uikit

I am updating my app to `iOS8`.

My app is crashing when calling presentViewController

```
UIViewController *vc = self.tmcWindow.rootViewController;
UIStoryboard *myboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle: nil];

UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewController"];
[vc presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

its working fine in `iOS7`.

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: What's the crash log, what does it say?

Comment: Same here crash log shows up exc bad access more than that it does't say anything.

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: I could solve using answer stated, this might be helpful for you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26157416/2728432

Comment: What kind of `UIViewController` is `AnotherViewController`? Is it just a `UIViewController` or is it some subclass of it?