# UIViewController presentViewController crashing on ios 8

Tags: ios8, uikit

Just got this error in our error logging system, been searching hi and low and can't seem to find any solution.  Any help is appreciated. Here is the [stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/hermanccw/2a9264fd77d46e0e7279).

Answer (score 1):

May be in your XCODE log you might have encountered this message

> "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is
>   discouraged ".

If yes then then try

`[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:myVC];`

if this fails then make sure you call presentViewController:myVC on immediate presenting ViewController i.e. in your case what I see from trace - CalendarEventDetailViewController.

If that too fail then go backward - from where you are invoking VC which in turn use presentViewController, in iOS8 presentation layer has changed specially WRT UIAlert/UIActionSheet, and UIPopovers,
 if you are using any of these, create UIAlertController as a separate code track for iOS8 and use presentViewController:myVC on presenting ViewController.

I was facing similar issue where presentViewController: not working at all or disrupting presenting VC contents, in some situations dismissViewController was crashing. Using this approach I could fix it.